# What is an alternate method to send keys to an application without being detected by keyloggers?

Tags: c, windows, architecture, open-source

What is the alternate method to send keys to an application without being detected by keyloggers, even not been detected by SetWindowsHookEx LowLevel Keyboard Hooking. I know there are Virtual Keyboards that are used for this purpose but I want its technique? Is there any opensource project related to it?

Comment: "closed by casperOne" WTF? there is no ambiguous, vague or incomplete question it's just a great and very common question! moderators begin to be very heavy.. moderator just doesn't understand questions BTW, close treasure topics uselessly...

Comment: This question should be re-opened.  The only problem seems to be the word "best," which could easily be interpreted concretely in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WM_SETTEXT message to directly set the text value of a particular edit box in the target application, but you have to inject your process into the target process first.

The advantage of doing this is that even if the message is hooked using SetWindowHookEx, there is no way to find out the string without likewise injecting the process. To realistically intercept this kind of message the malware would have to hook every single process on the computer and even then it would do no good because most text is not keyboard text, so the malware would have no way to know what was keyboard text and what was not.

Another method is to use WM_COPYDATA, but that is externally hookable.

Comment: What about console applications?

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to send ASCII string via the clipboard, is a clever method used by some program like the good KeePassX or PasswordSafe by Bruce Schneier

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this being the best way? What's to stop me from writing a keylogger that also monitors the clipboard?

Comment: That is not very useful for three reasons: 1. You can easily paste the clipboard contents at the wrong place. 2. Monitoring the clipboard is trivial. 3. How will you put the string in the clipboard in the first place?

Comment: Quite honestly, KeepassX and friends are more intended to protect against [shoulder-surfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_surfing_%28computer_security%29) and offline attacks (e.g. laptop theft). Using the clipboard is the only way to do that - and at least KeepassX takes care to clear the clipboard after some time to minimize the risk. Bun in my opinion, if someone can access your clipboard you are probably in a very deep mess anyway...

Comment: I assumed the keylogger was looking at key strokes only. The safest way would be sending encrypted data to the application which in turn would decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's sufficient to send a 4 or 6-digit PIN, your application could ask to enter it through a random mapping ->

```
    (1)  (2)  (3)
    zih  lbg  qsw

    (4)  (5)  (6)
    ukx  ...  ...
```

Code 1234 would be entered as ibqu or zlsx.
Of course this is compromised at the instant of customer actually entering his PIN as digits...

This method becomes increasingly annoying when the length increases -- so I offer this as only an alternative as asked in your title, not the best.